# shutdown() and close() does nothing

Tags: c, sockets, shutdown

I got a server listening on a tcp port. When there is an incoming connection it uses `accept()` and spawns a child process using `fork()`. The client/child process reads some data from the connection and sends it back to the server through a pipe. After this, I would like to close the connection. I have tried to use `shutdown()` and `close()` from the client process without much luck.

I've checked the results of both `shutdown()` and `close()` and they both return 0. So apparently they run without a hitch. After both `shutdown()` and `close()` has been run the server receive a `sigchld` from the child process. This is being handled on a general basis, but I would prefer to close down the connection before receiving the signal.
Any suggestions regarding how to do this would be much appreciated.

On a side note `close()` has been used to close unneeded file descriptors and sockets throughout the server/client program, but now I'm unsure if these are actually getting closed.

Below are two code snippets.
First off is the `accept()` and `fork()` in the server part of the program:

```
if ((client_s = accept(s, &info.addr, &addrlen)) == -1) {
    //Error handling
}
if ((info.pid = fork()) == -1) {
    //More error handling
}
else if (info.pid == 0) {
    //Closing all unneeded file descriptors

    // Set default signal handler for SIGCHLD
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);

    _exit(clientStatus_main(client_s, info_pipes[1]));
}
else {
    //Adding client to list of clients and closing some file descriptors.
    close(client_s);
}
```

Finally a code snippet from the function clientStatus_main:

```
//Signal handling
signal(SIGINT, client_sighandler);
signal(SIGTERM, client_sighandler);
signal(SIGKILL, client_sighandler);
signal(SIGHUP, client_sighandler);
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);

//Read data from socket
read(socket, &status_packet.type, iLength)
//Do data handling and write back to server
write(info_pipe, &status_packet, status_packet.len)

//Close down socket
res = shutdown(socket, SHUT_RDWR);
addlog(LOG_INFO, "Result of shutdown: %i\n", res); //Write to log
res = close(socket);
addlog(LOG_INFO, "Result of close: %i\n", res);
return (iCount > 0 ? 0 : -1);
```

Any good ideas?

***EDIT:** After reading the comments I've tried to do `close(client_s)` from the parent process, but it didn't solve my problem. For clarity, I've also added the line to the code snippet.

Comment: You omited the interesting part: "closing some file descriptors" in the else part.

Comment: "//Adding client to list of clients and closing some file descriptors." , So which file descriptors did you close ? Did you `close(client_s)` ?

Comment: No, I did not `close(client_s)`. Is it necessary to close the file descriptor from the parent process as well as from the client?

Comment: Yes, both copies of the `fork()`ed process have a copy of the file descriptor. The socket is closed when all of them have been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of embarrassing, but it seems that the problem wasn't with `close()` or `shutdown()` after all. The comments and the answer by Klas Lindbäck got me thinking and I experimented a bit and found that the `SIGCHLD` was sent because the client actually closed down the connection at the same time the child process did.

So my solution has been inspired by the suggestion by Klas Lindbäck. The child process sends the process ID through the pipe mentioned earlier and the parent process can now safely ignore/block the `SIGCHLD` sent from this process.

Answer (score 1):

There are three processes involved:

**The client**: connect to the listening socket of the parent.

**The parent**: server process that listens on a socket, accepts connections and hands them over to a child.

**The child**: server process that talks to the client over the established connection.

The established connection exists only between `the child` and `the client`. `The parent` has no way of detecting when the client socket is closed down from either side.

There are two ways to inform `the parent` that `the child` is closing the connection and terminating, either catch the `SIGCHLD` signal or let `the child` send a message to `the parent`, for instance over the `pipe` mentioned in the question.

Comment: The description/explanation is great - but I am unsure what the parent should do with the information about the connection being closed by the child... I have already tried the `close()` as described in the edit of the question.
As for catching the `SIGCHLD` in the parent process - this is already being done. As I recall (correct me if I am wrong), the signal could also be interpreted as something went wrong - the connection got interrupted or some such. I would very much like to distinguish between this situation and that.

Comment: I would handle client errors in the child if I could. The child can detect if the client closes the socket or if the connection times out and should be able to handle it. If you can't do adequate error handling in the child, then I suggest the second approach: the child informs the parent in some way, for instance by sending a message through the pipe.

Comment: Well, handling the `SIGCHLD` (in the parent process or in the child) does not help me with regard to closing the connection. My main question was how to close the connection :o) The `SIGCHLD` was actually just how I realized the connection was not closed.